# Create ReaderT[F, D, A] from F[A]

Tags: scala, scala-cats, reader-monad

```
type MapReaderOrOption[A] = ReaderT[Option, Map[String,String], A]
```

I can create it from `ReaderT.apply`:

```
def f:MapReaderOrOption[Int] = ReaderT(_ => Option(10))
```

From A type via type enrichment and pure method:

```
import cats.Applicative
import cats.syntax.int._
def f:MapReaderOrOption[Int] = 10.pure[MapReaderOrOption]
```

I'd like to find something similar. Each time to use ReaderT(..) not so convenient. For sure, I can create a helper method. The question, are there other options?

Expected something like:

```
def f:MapReaderOrOption[Int] = Option(10).asReaderT[MapReaderOrOption]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
type MapReaderOrOption[A] = ReaderT[Option, Map[String,String], A]

implicit class toReader[F[_],T](f: F[T]) {
  def asReaderT[K] = ReaderT[F,K,T](_ => f)
}

def f:MapReaderOrOption[Int] = Option(10).asReaderT
```

or in case type of `f` is not provided explicitly you need to define `K` parameter.

```
def f = Option(10).asReaderT[Map[String,String]]
```

So now type for `f` will be inferred to `ReaderT[Option, Map[String,String], Int]`. I think you don't even need type alias in this case.

or one more alternative

```
def f = Option(10).asReaderT:MapReaderOrOption[Int]
```

Answer (score 7):

Methods that take an `F[A]` and lift it into an `HK[F, A]` for some higher-kinded construction `HK` are consistently called `liftF` across the library.

In your case, it would be `Kleisli.liftF`, since `ReaderT` is just an alias for `Kleisli`:

```
import cats.data.ReaderT
import cats.data.Kleisli.liftF

type MapReaderOpt[A] = ReaderT[Option, Map[String, String], A]
val x: MapReaderOpt[Int] = liftF(Option(42))
```

If `liftF` seems too vague, you could still rename it into `{liftF => liftToReaderT}` during a renaming import.

Comment: It seems that type definition for `x` is required here as well because second type parameter is invariant and inferred to `Nothing` making `ReaderT` inferred for `x` incompatible with `MapReaderOpt[Int]`

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko That might indeed be the case, thanks. Ascribed the type explicitly instead of leaving it to the comments. Usually, this is not a problem, because the type is inferred from the context.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, by the way, is there a way to create ReaderT[F,D,A] from D via a  method similar to liftF? Except ReaderT.apply of cause.

Comment: @Alexandr Not sure how a single `D` could be enough to create a `ReaderT[F, D, A]` - who or what would specify how to construct the `A`?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin,  a good question. I will rephrase it. A function returns ReaderT[F,D,A] and this function composes other functions that also return ReaderT[F,D,A] via for-comprehension. Sometimes I want to be able not to pass D to that small functions, but invoke functions on instance of D, inside for-comrehension. So I must somehow, create ReaderT[F,D,D], (I think) from D. Hope I was clear enough now, otherwise will create a separate issue with exact usecase.

Comment: @Alexandr The [`object Kleisli.ask`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/data/Kleisli$.html#ask) seems to have the signature that you want.